# How to provide test data and classes in multi-module gradle projects

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I want to provide downstream modules with test data/classes from an upstream module. What's the best way to do this?

Let's say I have the following modules:

`:data-transactions` - 
Has an interface `TransactionsCache`. This module by default will provide a `TransactionDbCache` which backs this cache with SQLite.

`:ui-transactions` - requires an instance of `TransactionsCache` to display the transactions to the user. This module is dependant on `:data-transactions`.

**What I want**

- While testing `:ui-transactions`, I want to provide a fake implementation of `TransactionsCache`, like `TransactionsInMemoryCache`. Other downstream modules of `:data-transactions` may need `TransactionsInMemoryCache` too. This class should NOT be included in non-test modules.
- These test dependencies like `TransactionsInMemoryCache` should be able to leverage kotlin the `internal` visibility modifier - i.e. be in the same module as `:data-transactions`

I'm guessing that the solution here is something to do with `srcSets` and a special `testHelper` configuration?

note: this is for android, so I'd need to generate an APK. is this possible without flavors?

Answer (score 1):

There's two approaches

1. Create a test jar in the same project as the main jar which can be used as a test dependency in other projects. This jar will be the combination of `src/test/java` (compiled) and `src/test/resources`
2. Create a separate project for the common test utilities which can be used as a test dependency in other projects

I, myself, prefer option 2 as I feel it's the most cleanest approach since you put exactly what you want in the jar (test utilities, abstract base classes, test resources etc) and you don't include actual tests in the jar.

See [nebula-test-jar](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.nebula-test-jar) plugin for option 1. Note that nebula have deprecated this plugin in favour of option 2

Comment: couldn't I just define a custom configuration of `src/fakes/java` and build a .jar off that? 

The trick though is that I want downstream modules whose `main` classpath depends on the upstream module's `main`. but for the downstream `test` classpath to depend on the upstream's `fakes` classpath. Do you get a conflict here, because downstream's `test` configuration extends from its `main` configuration, where this `main` configuration depends on the upstream `main`, while the downstream `test` depends on the upstream `fakes`?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do all that custom config when you get everything for free if you put it in another module of a multi-module build (option 2)